# I want to attach an API key to my URL to give access to the database, the problem is attaching it to the filename

Tags: javascript, html, backend, api-key, webdatarocks

I want to attach an API key to my URL to give access to the database, the problem is attaching it to the filename

```js
var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
    container: "#wdr-component",
    toolbar: true,
    report: {
        dataSource: {
            filename: "https://testing-195b.restdb.io/rest/customerdata"
        }
    }
});
```

this code worked for the console

```js
  var settings = {
    "async": true,
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": "https://testing-195b.restdb.io/rest/customerdata",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "x-apikey": "60c8b39ee2c96c46a2463581",
      "cache-control": "no-cache"
      
    }
  }
  
  $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    
  });
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I am working with a database called restdb.io, a Web page API key (CORS) was generated ,which I need if am to gain access into my database, the problem here is I am using a web reporting tool which have there own syntax, I need to find way to attach the API key  or bypass an error  "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it is needed to pass the request headers, it's better to get the data by making a request separately from WebDataRocks. This way it can contain all the needed information. After that, the data can be fed from the webpage to WebDataRocks the following way:

```
var pivot = new WebDataRocks({
    container: "#wdr-component",
    toolbar: true,
    report: {
        dataSource: {
            data: yourData // your variable containing the data
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, was able to use "fetch" to get and store the data

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the API-key as an URL parameter like this:

"https://testing-195b.restdb.io/rest/customerdata?apikey=XXXXXXXX"

Comment: thanks for the contribution, but unfortunately this method still doesn't work, the error :"It seems that this file doesn't exist or 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is absent in the resource requested",  still appears.

Comment: Have you checked the Cors settings for this API-key? Domain and path must match, but for test you can use /** for path and * for domain